# Generic List Method Problem

Tags: c#, generics, list

I'm getting an error when I try to create a method with the following signature:

```
public List<T> CreateList(DataSet dataset)


Error 1 The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, helped me out loads!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`T` must be declared either at the method level:

```
public List<T> CreateList<T>(DataSet dataset)
```

or at the containing class level:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public List<T> CreateList(DataSet dataset)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But be careful to **not** declare it at both places:

```
// Don't do this
public class Foo<T>
{
    public List<T> CreateList<T>(DataSet dataset)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're defining a generic method, the type placeholder should be part of the method declaration, not only of its return type. Try:

```
public List<T> CreateList<T>(DataSet dataset)
```